# JavaFX Scene Builder : make gridpane wrapped into scrollpane remain in corner when resizing

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm making this UI where an image map is displayed, wrapped into an anchor pane, itself wrapped into a scrollpane. I want to add an overlay at the bottom left corner, showing coordinates. This overlay must of course be visible even when resizing my view and scrolling my map left and right. 
I tried to use constraints with the anchorpane but the coordinates field disappears when scrolling the map rightward.
Here you can see a view of my hierarchy and the position I want the field to remain :
[scene builder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0ng1.png)
Thx for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SplitPane
  └AnchorPane
    ├ScrollPane
    │  └... 
    └Label(etc)
```

To overlap the label, I recommend the above construction. This is because the label is out of the viewport, making the viewport zoom and transform easier.

Considering a case horizontal `ScrollBar` is invisible, `LayoutY` of the label should be compute using binding.

```
// These can be set in Scene Builder
anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane, label);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(label, 0.0);

// Bind LayoutY of Label
DoubleBinding labelLayoutYBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
        () -> scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight() - label.getHeight(),
        label.heightProperty(),
        scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty());
labelLayoutYBinding.addListener((o, ov, nv) -> label.setLayoutY(nv.doubleValue()));
```

---

If the horizontal `ScrollBar` is always displayed in your application, setting fixed bottom offset in Scene Builder is easier rather than using the binding.

```
// This can be set in Scene Builder
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(label, 13.0); // Set the fixed value to ease up
```

Comment: Though I didn't understand very well the "Bind LayoutY of Label" part of your answer (so I tried without implementing it), it works! I know understand the purpose of constraints and anchorpanes.Thanks for the time spent!